# strpos fails unexpectedly

Tags: php, strpos

Question, how come the following executed the echo:

```
$str = "Hello World";

if (strpos($str, 'He') !== false) {
    echo 'GOOD';
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
$str = "Hello World";

if (strpos($str, 'He') === true) {
    echo 'GOOD';
}
```

Aren't the two conditions equivalent in that they are both checking for the returned to be a boolean that is set to true? Isn't !== false the same as === true, and if not, why not?

I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: The purpose of `strpos` is not to return a boolean, but an index if it succeeds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No they're not equivalent:

[strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns either boolean `FALSE` (if not found) or an integer offset value (which can be `0` if found at offset 0 and so on), but it never returns a boolean `TRUE`. ie., Boolean `TRUE` !== an `INT`.

Comment: You could test for `isnumeric(strpos(...))` or `is_int(strpos(...))` but that's less performant than simply testing for `!== false`

Comment: I figured, it is not optimal, thats why I edited my response. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The operator `===` compares not only value but also a datatype. If `strpos` finds the substring, it returns the position which is of type `int`. As it is not bool, the condition is not met.